# evaluate string arithmetic expression using python

Tags: python

How can I evaluate following:

```
a=b=c=d=e=0  # initially
```

if user enters:

```
"a=b=4" as a string, it should modify the existing value.
```

So result would be something like a=4, b=4
if user enters:

```
"a=(c=4)*2", it should evaluate as expression and update the values.
```

so result would be something like a=8, c=4

The brackets can be nested further.

Any help would be really appreciated. I am using python.

Comment: Take a look at expression trees, it is what you will need to be doing here.

Comment: using the variables as string inside the expression is creating trouble :(

Answer (score 3):

If this is a trivial console script where security is absolutely no concern, you can use `exec()` to execute mathematical statements. However, python does not support code such as `a=(c=4)*2`, so it won't be possible to do natively.

**However**, `exec()` is a gaping security hole if this is running on, say, a web server. If this is expected to be something where untrusted and potentially malicious users can submit commands, you should look into either sanitizing it and parsing it yourself, or [implementing sandboxing.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysandbox/)

**TL;DR** Since you're working on custom commands not supported, you should write your own parser to handle and execute these without worrying about executing untrusted code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is writing a parser for this particular grammar (the worst is something involving eval/exec - submitting user-provided content to these functions is a security can of worms).

Take a look at this example:

- http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/detail/SimpleCalc.py

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing